# How to add clickable margins around an icon in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, touch, openlayers-3

I'm using [openlayers 3](http://openlayers.org) to show a map with some markers that have a small icon. Upon clicking one of them, the browser switches to another page associated with the marker.

The markers are currently implemented as features:

```
const style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        src: img_url,
    })
});

const feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([x, y]),
});

feature.setStyle(style);
```

Here's my click handler:

```
map.on("click", e => {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, (feature) => {
        window.location.href = "/s/" + feature.getId();
        return true; // stop after first feature
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the icons are quite small and therefore hard to hit on a touch-based interface such as an iPad.

Is there an accepted way of making the target larger? My ideas are the following:

- Create an additional invisible marker for each marker and make those clickable.
- Instead of only using the event's location, I could sample some pixels around it and use all features nearby.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you create an invisible square around your icon like:

```
const style = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      src: img_url,
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: [0, 0, 0, 0] }),
      points: 4,
      radius: 50, // <--------- control its size
      angle: Math.PI / 4
    })
  })
];
```

Comment: This approach has a small problem: When not specifying the `fill` property, the console says: *expected color, but found '0'*. This might not be future-proof. If I supply a color, I cannot make it completely transparent, because in that case it is not clickable, so I have to make it almost transparent.

Comment: I'm currently stuck on version 3.8.1 though, so maybe this has changed in the meantime.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly API docs says `fill` can be `undefined`. I don't see that console message with 3.8, 3.12 and latest.

Comment: Might depend on the browser. I believe this is the same bug: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4074. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've initially tried out Jonatas' approach where I add a larger style. This works quite well. One caveat is that upon clicking on a feature, we have to figure out which feature is the closest because they can easily overlap.

I've finally decided to go with a slightly different approach after discovering the `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate()` method. I do everything in the `click` handler:

```
map.on("click", event => {
    const distance = feature => {
        const coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coords);
        const distSquared = Math.pow(event.pixel[0] - pixel[0], 2)
                          + Math.pow(event.pixel[1] - pixel[1], 2);
        return distSquared;
    };

    const clickedFeature = { feat: null, dist: Infinity };

    /* See if we clicked on a feature. If yes, take closest */
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
        const dist = distance(feature);
        if (dist < clickedFeature.dist) {
            clickedFeature.feat = feature;
            clickedFeature.dist = dist;
        }
    });

    /* If we are touch-based, we also take into account clicks that happen nearby */
    if (!clickedFeature.feat) {
        if (ol.has.TOUCH) {
            const coords = this._map.getCoordinateFromPixel(event.pixel);
            const closestFeat = this._featureSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coords);

            const dist = distance(closestFeat);
            /* touch size taken from Apple's guidelines */
            if (dist < Math.pow(22,2)) {
                clickedFeature.feat = closestFeat;
                clickedFeature.dist = dist;
            }
        }
    }

    /* go to station */
    if (clickedFeature.feat) {
        window.location.href = "/s/" + clickedFeature.feat.getId();
    }
});
```